# How to store multiple input fields and radio button in a single state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
 const [isPublished, setIsPublished] = useState(false);
  const handleRadio = (event: { currentTarget: { value: string } }) => {
    const isPublished = event.currentTarget.value === 'true' ? true : false;
    setValues({ isPublished });
  };
const initialValues = {
    code: '',
    product: '',
    checked: false,
    jobCardNo: '',
    datePicker1: '',
    datePicker2: '',
    serial: '',
    technicalNo: '',
    lineNo: '',
    show: false,
  };
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const handleInput = (e: { target: { name: any; value: any } }) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

Here I am setting up multiple input fields in a single state. I want to update radio button checked in a single state object.Please let me how to do this in these situations

```
<div className="radio">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      value="true"
                      checked={values.checked === true}
                      onChange={handleRadio}
                    />
                    Yes
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      value="false"
                      checked={values.checked === false}
                      onChange={handleRadio}
                    />
                    No
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some changes I've made
please follow the link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-rain-857z8b?file=/src/App.js

I've just added name for `radio inputs` and used one `handleInput` handler.

Here's a code example:

```
const initialValues = { 
  code: "", product: "",
  checked: "false",
  jobCardNo: "",
  datePicker1: "",
  datePicker2: "",
  serial: "",
  technicalNo: "",
  lineNo: "",
  show: false
};
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
const handleInput = (e) => { 
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setValues({ ...values, [name]: value }); 
};

return (
  <div className="radio">
    <input
      type="radio"
      value="true"
      name="checked"
      checked={values.checked === "true"}
      onChange={handleInput} 
    />
    Yes
    <input
      type="radio"
      value="false"
      name="checked"
      checked={values.checked === "false"}
      onChange={handleInput}
    />
    No
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
    const handleRadio = (event) => {
        let value = event.target.value
        let name = event.target.name
        setValues({ ...input, [name]: value })
    }
```

add a name in input for handleRadio

```
  <input
      type="radio"
      value="true"
      name="name here"
      checked={values.checked === true}
      onChange={handleRadio}
   />
```